# Is my Data Access model acceptable?

Tags: list, splist, data

I'm creating a SharePoint application and want to do things the right way as often as possible.

I'm deploying a series of Lists in a Site Definition, and I want to lock down Data Access to a series of Get() methods to maintain conventions.

Some of my lists have SecurityBits="22" set in the list definition, because I want List Item entries to be modified only in the UI.

I want to avoid abusing `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges`. I also want to sidestep the limitation of `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges` where you cannout have `return` functions in the delegates.

This seems like a good way to enforce this. If you're calling a list to get list items with normal security, you can call `var PostList = CoreLists.Posts`. If you need to call that same list with elevated permissions, you can call `var PostList = CoreLists.SystemAccount.Posts`

Is this a good way to do this?

```
public static class CoreLists
{
    public static SPList Posts()
    {
        return SPContext.Current.Web.GetList(SPContext.Current.Web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/lists/CommunityPost");
    }
    public static class SystemAccount
    {
        public static SPList Posts()
        {
            using (var elevatedSite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.ID, SPContext.Current.Site.SystemAccount.UserToken))
            using (var web = elevatedSite.OpenWeb())
                return web.GetList(web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/lists/CommunityPost");
        }
    }
}
```